# How to retrieve specific node from firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase in my android application. I am following documentation for [Saving](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html) and [retrieving](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html),
But the Sample database(Dragon) which is used in tutorial has different structure than my database.

This is my code for Pushing the data to firebase

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog");
                User userName = new User(socialNum, name, datofBirth, mob1, mob2, healthCondition);
                Firebase usersRef = myFirebaseRef.child(name);
                Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
                users.put(name, userName);                    
              myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(users);
```

which create database format like this

```
{
      "android" : {
        "saving-data" : {
          "fireblog" : {
            "-JiRtkpIFLVFNgmNBpMj" : {
              "Name" : {
                "birthDate" : "100",
                "fullName" : "Name",
                "healthCond" : "fyhft",
                "mob1" : "5855",
                "mob2" : "5858",
                "socialNumber" : "100"
              }
            },
            "-JiRv0RmHwWVHSOiZXiN" : {
              "mast" : {
                "birthDate" : "100",
                "fullName" : "mast",
                "healthCond" : "fyhft",
                "mob1" : "5855",
                "mob2" : "5858",
                "socialNumber" : "100"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to Retrieve data from firebase such that, if I put "full Name" in my apps search box, it should retrieve that specific node, so that I can populate that information in Listview.

This is How I am trying to retrieve,

```
final String Find = find.getText().toString();   //Get text for search edit text box
                Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog");
                Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("fullName");
               // System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey() + "is" + value.get("socialNumber"));
                System.out.println(Find);

                queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChild) {
                        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                        Map<String,Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                        String name1 = String.valueOf(value.get("fullName"));
                    //System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey() + "is" + value.get("fullName").toString());
                    if (name1.equals(Find)){
                        System.out.println("Name" + value.get("fullName"));
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("its is null");
                    }

                    }
```

but It returns all the nodes,

```
02-19 12:18:02.053    8269-8269/com.example.nilesh.firebasetest I/System.out﹕ name
02-19 12:18:05.426    8269-8269/com.example.nilesh.firebasetest I/System.out﹕ {Name={socialNumber=100, birthDate=100, fullName=Name, mob1=5855, mob2=5858, healthCond=fyhft}}
02-19 12:18:05.426    8269-8269/com.example.nilesh.firebasetest I/System.out﹕ its is null
02-19 12:18:05.426    8269-8269/com.example.nilesh.firebasetest I/System.out﹕ {mast={socialNumber=100, birthDate=100, fullName=mast, mob1=5855, mob2=5858, healthCond=fyhft}}
02-19 12:18:05.426    8269-8269/com.example.nilesh.firebasetest I/System.out﹕ its is null
```

How can i Retrieve specific node so that If I enter fullName = mast, it should retrieve only second node with all the fields in that node.

Comment: It looks like there is a superfluous level of children. The data is structured as `saving-data/fireblog/<record id>/fluff/...actual data...` and the `fluff` layer needs to be removed for those queries to work. You can't query children of children.

Comment: @Kato , Yes I noticed that and modified my Push code.The query works now. However now another problem I'm facing now in  *If(Data not found )* condition. As this query goes through all the nodes one by one, I cant get my code in *else{} statement* to work. I considered using 'queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent' but then query returns all the nodes

Comment: That sounds like an answer @kato. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen feel free to add a note in your answer since that one will be referenced by anyone visiting the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I have question. Why does the same query (_Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo("gooner");_) returns different results in _queryRef.addChildEventListener()_  and  _queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()_ ? First one returns single specific node while second returns all the nodes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're creating a query in this line:

```
Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("fullName");
```

Like that the query orders the child nodes by their `fullName` value. But it doesn't yet limit what child nodes are returned.

To limit the nodes, you also have to filter. e.g.:

```
Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo("gooner");
```

You can also get a range of nodes, by filtering with `startAt` and/or `endAt` instead of `equalTo`.

As Kato commented:

> It looks like there is a superfluous level of children. The data is structured as `saving-data/fireblog/<record id>/fluff/...actual data..`. and the fluff layer needs to be removed for those queries to work. You can't query children of children.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am accepting your answer, However @Kato 's comment was much helpful for me. Can u also please help me understand difference between *queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()* and *queryRef.addChildEventListener()*  with best use case scenario?

Comment: @gooner using the Query for SingleValueEvent will register a ValueEvent for that query one time and when the operation is done it will remove the listener automatically.
The addChildEventListener, you register a ChildEventListener that will listen for changes in each one of the child nodes in the node you are querying

Comment: How to retrieve all the nodes who have certain value same. 
like all Houses with Blue paint

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get value of specif node or child node like this

[image]

Here if you want to get child node(address) value. You can get it in this way

```
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    myRef = database.getReference();
    final DatabaseReference orders_Reference = myRef.child("Order");


 orders_Reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(data.getKey().equals("address")){
                String orderNumber = data.getValue().toString();
                Log.d("Specific Node Value" , orderNumber);
               }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to retrieve single value from firebase database using Hashmap.

```
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> AllUserscourselist;
 String SelectedCourseUserUId;
     DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

     databaseReference.child("User_course_Details").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //                        emergencyContactsList = new ArrayList<>();
                    AllUserscourselist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {

                            for (DataSnapshot courseUID : postSnapShot.getChildren()){
                                UsercourseDetails usercourseDetails = courseUID.getValue(UsercourseDetails.class);
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                String user_id = postSnapShot.getKey();
                                String course_id = usercourseDetails.getcourse_id();
                                String course_type = usercourseDetails.getcourse_type();
                                String course_brand = usercourseDetails.course_brand;
                                String course_number_plate_url = usercourseDetails.course_number_plate_url;

                                map.put("user_id", user_id);
                                map.put("course_id", course_id);
                                map.put("course_type", course_type);
                                map.put("course_brand", course_brand);
                                map.put("course_number_plate_url", course_number_plate_url);

                                AllUserscourselist.add(map);
                            }

    //                        AllUserscourselist.add(new UsercourseDetails(usercourseDetails.getcourse_type(),usercourseDetails.getcourse_brand(),usercourseDetails.getcourse_number_plate_url(),usercourseDetails.getcourse_id()));
                        }

                        Log.e("AllUserscourselist",""+AllUserscourselist);

                        courseIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < AllUserscourselist.size(); i++) {
                            String course_id_list;
                            course_id_list = AllUserscourselist.get(i).get("course_id")+" "+ AllUserscourselist.get(i).get("user_id");
                            courseIdList.add(course_id_list);
                        }

                        if(courseIdList.size()>0 && courseIdList!=null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < courseIdList.size(); i++) {   //used
                                String arr[] = courseIdList.get(i).split(" ");
                                if (arr[0].equals(coursenumber)) {
                                    SelectedcourseUserUId = arr[1];
                                    getUserEmergencyContacts(SelectedcourseUserUId);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }else{
    //                    NavigationActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, R.anim.anim_slide_in_left);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting all the nodes and then iterating it to get nodes based on value,
just trigger the query provided by firebase.

```
   private void readAllRequestedFormFromFirebaseDb(){
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("App_DB");
    DatabaseReference childRef = ref.child("AllRequest");
    Query queryRef = 
  childRef.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo("Jay");
    queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            // getting list
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                QueryFormModel post = dataSnapshot.getValue(QueryFormModel.class);
                queryFormModelArrayList.add(post);
                /*the above list will have record only
                 with the provided fullName as Jay*/

            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("DetailsActivity", "onCancelled:readAllSubmittedRequestFromFirebaseDb:  "+databaseError );
        }
    });
}
```

[Click here and find the beautifully written post about this topic](https://www.javaoneworld.com/2021/12/how-to-retrieve-specific-node-from-firebase-databse-in-android-based-on-value.html)