# How to retrieve specific list of data from firebase

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to `firebase` and `nosql` database

I am trying to retrieve some specific data from a Firebase. I have a node `universities` and that node has many unique identifier as node which has so more data into it. I want to retrieve `name` from each node.

Please have a look at this.

[image]

What I have tried so far: I tried using `addChildEventListener` but this only listens first child. I've debugged it and it was only showing the values of the first child of `universities` node.

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            List<University> university = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            Log.d("TAG",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have also tried `addValueEventListener`. This listens the whole node and return whole data, but I am unable to extract "name" for it since it contains unique identifiers.

Please guide me into the right directions.

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                University university = dataSnapshot.getValue(University.class);
                List<University> universities = (List<University>) dataSnapshot.getValue(University.class);
                *//*List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                lst.add(dsp.getKey());
            }
            Log.d("TAG",lst.toString());*//*

            Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();


            *//*List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>(td.values());
            List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
                list.add((String) values.get(i));
            }*//*
            Log.d("TAG", university.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you using `addValueEventListener` for retrieve all university from Firebase

```
List<University> universityList = new ArrayList<>();
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        universityList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            University university = postSnapshot.getValue(University.class);
            universityList.add(university);

            // here you can access to name property like university.name

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Or if you using `addChildEventListener`

```
List<University> universityList = new ArrayList<>();
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         University university = dataSnapshot.getValue(University.class);
         universityList.add(university);
         Log.i(TAG,"add university name = " + university.name);
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok i used the first one method. That method. Store hashMap type data into list. I mean it has total 3 index now. And each index contains HashMap kind of data. And i want to get name out of it. how would i do it?

Comment: I see the way use using in your post is different. in my code (in one method) , inside the for loop you will get the Univerty object, and use can access to name property by university.name

Comment: thank you it's working for me. keep going

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Linh's answer about using the `addEventListener` method. You can use `GenericTypeIndicator` in order to directly create the list of objects you'll be needing. Here's a quick example:

```
List<University> universityList = new ArrayList<>();
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<List<University>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<University>>() {};
        universityList = snapshot.getValue(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: By using this method, make sure the data you upload is exactly a single List object by `setValue()`, not by `.push().setValue()`, otherwise you would get this exception: `Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap`

Answer (score 2):

You can use equalTo() of [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) in which you can pass your custom string to match with firebase database.

like this way you can create your Query and set listener with that

```
Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("some name");
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601663/how-to-retrieve-specific-node-from-firebase-database-in-android) thread for more.

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database) is nice example from firebase officials, refer that and you will get clear idea

Comment: would this query return me name from each child of universities node? ```Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("name")``` ?

Comment: @Zeeshan Shabbir No, it will return all users ordered by property name values.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
               list.add(user);
           }
       }
```

**class User**

```
class User{

String name;

String phone;

public String getname() {
    return name;
}

public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getphone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setphone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

**List bind with class**

```
List<User> list== new ArrayList <>();
```

**100% it will work**

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem .You can just change the access specifier i.e public to private in the Model class you problem will be solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).