# Android Studio Application display problem

Tags: android, firebase, github

I was making an app where it fetches specific data from the database to the app and display it in a recycler view, but I have a problem that I don't know how to fix, I'm pretty sure it has to do with the `HomeFragment.java`. Please check the multi-line comment near the end of the script. I will add the GitHub Repo because I don't think it is a single-file error.

Sorry for the pain and suffering you might encounter in advance for being so vague, but I don't know how to say it any better.

BlogRecyclerAdapter.Java: https://pastebin.com/39G2mEW5

HomeFragment.Java: https://pastebin.com/YmKs5QUJ

Thank You!

REPO: https://github.com/hjdaboss123/BlindNews

Path to `HomeFragment.javaBlind:News/app/src/main/java/com/blindnews/kimh2/blindnews`

EDIT1: 
Added pastebin for code on Recycler Adapter and HomeFragment

Comment: whats the problem ; dose the code run; whats the logcat stacktrace

Comment: The code runs perfectly, no warnings or errors, but it doesn't display the elements in the recycler view when i run it on an emulator. hope this helps :)

Comment: Also, how do you find the logcat stacktrace @AkashPal

Comment: when you run the app it shows in Logcat ussually at bottom of the window

Comment: what i think is your problem is that you need o set the blog_list after the event is complete and then call for notifydatasetchangesd()

Comment: I am looking at the logcat right now, but it keeps on adding new stuff, is there a way sort what you asked me to find? @AkashPal

Comment: yeah but for that you need to add Log.d("TAG", "info"); in your code

Comment: I looked at the code, you need to update the list inside your adapter. Just add adapter and fragment code here and we suggest a solution. `Logcat` won't help.

Comment: and in the logcat just search for that particular TAG

Comment: logcat will be helpful to know wheter the blogs are added or not

Comment: i would suggest please learn how to use logcat

Comment: I have just updated the question to show pastebin for both 2 files. I couldnt format the code in the stackoverflow format though,

Comment: Basically what Akash is suggesting is to learn to debug your code. Read here https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the full solution to the problem but in comments we figured out the problem which was, OP using `Firestore` to get data from `Realtime database`.

Change this in fragment -

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    blog_list = new ArrayList<>();
    blog_list_view = view.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_view);

    blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);
    blog_list_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext()));
    blog_list_view.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);

    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore.collection("articles").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);
                    blog_list.add(blogPost);
                }
            }
            Log.d("HomeFragment", "onCreateView: " + blog_list.size());
            //Send updated list to adapter.
            blogRecyclerAdapter.updatePosts(blog_list);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Handle updated list inside adapter -

```
public void updatePosts(List<BlogPost> blogPostList) {
    //if you want to update the whole list. If you want to append, List has addAll method I think and use it with notifyItemRangeInserted for better performance.
    this.blog_list = blogPostList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the code still doesn't show what I want it to show, could it be a Firebase permissions issue? or is it still purely my code.

Comment: Add a log just before updating the adapter and check the size of the list. This log will appear in logcat, Use tag to search if you don't find it. Added in the solution.

Comment: it comes up to 
2019-02-16 19:10:46.443 22979-22979/com.blindnews.kimh2.blindnews D/HomeFragment: onCreateView: 0
2019-02-16 19:10:46.443 22979-22979/com.blindnews.kimh2.blindnews D/HomeFragment: onCreateView: 0

Is there a way to retrieve the list of posts in the database regardless of whether one has been added or not?

Comment: What if you remove the if condition? `if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)`.

Comment: Wait, it still says onCreateView: 0. Is there a different for loop i could use? Like finding just elements instead of documentChanges?

Comment: Seems like you are actually not getting documents from `Firestore`. Do you have documents in `Firestore`?

Comment: Can you check from firebase console whether you have documents in `articles` collection in Firestore?

Comment: But this looks like `Realtime Database` and you are using `Firestore` in your code, They are different.

Comment: ahhhhhh. hm, is there a simple way to chage from firestore to realtime database? or viceverca?

Comment: Nope, If you are just starting with app side, shifting to `Realtime database` is easy and you don't have to change(backend logic) how you are storing in db. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Comment: would it be as simple as export, import? or do i need to do more

Comment: On the mobile side, it will be like using a different library(adding 1 line in dependency) and 4-5 lines of code in `HomeFragment`.

Comment: Although Firebase is moving onto Firestore, so you can also use it if you are in early stage of development, because it will have better support in future. Also there could be a solution to move your `realtime database` data to `Firestore`.  But read how different they are, they have different pricing plans https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore.

Comment: also, in case you DO know, i was wondering if you know how to solve this part of the code `BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);`

Comment: I can't seem to anything that can get the data from a DataSnapshot

Comment: I follow this document to get all documents from a collection in `Firestore`. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data. Yeah I also use `toObject()` method to cast result to a list.

Comment: but I need it to be a realtime database, is there a alternative that is for the RTDB?

Comment: Refer this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data. This might be more helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652007/how-to-retrieve-specific-list-of-data-from-firebase.