# Firebase recycler to retrieve data not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my data structure on firebase as in the image. I need ONLY the "Details" of each node in my recycler view. I`m not being able to figure out how the database reference should be in order to get data of details only for each user. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Data structure on firebase]

Getting null for details

[image: Getting null for details][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFMaf.png)

Comment: In the future, it would be better to paste your code inline, so if the person wants to edit your code, they don't have to rewrite the entire thing.

Comment: However, I would look at your firebase databaseReference:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstace().getReference("Doctors");` 

I could be wrong but I don't think it's necessary to cite child here. Though your structure is a bit ... well, your going to have to change the code a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601663/how-to-retrieve-specific-node-from-firebase-database-in-android Check marked answer there.

Comment: `detailsRef = databaseReference.orderByChild("Details");`

Comment: Please look at the new image I`ve put. I`m getting null for details.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database always returns complete nodes. It cannot return a subset of each node in a query. This is one of the many reasons why the Firebase documentation recommends flattening data.

In your scenario you should split out all the doctor information under separate top-level nodes. E.g.

```
DoctorsDetails
  Doctor1
    appointTime: 15
  Doctor2
    appointTime: 30
DoctorsLocations
  Doctor1
    location1: ...
  Doctor2
    location2: ...
```

Now you can bind your recycler view to just the data you need and prevent that your users have to download data that won't be displayed.